# Stripe API Description Not Creating New Lines

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe API as a gateway for payments, currently the description returns what the user buys ie in this picture that i outputted in console.

[image]

This is where the output comes from here:

```
 const checkout = await stripe.charges.create({
      amount: totalCost * 100,
      currency: "usd",
      description: itemInfo.join('\n'),
      receipt_email: billingInfo.email,
      source: token.id,
    });
    console.log(checkout.description)
```

I get the formatting from here:

```
const itemInfo = [];
  itemInfo.push(
    "CUSTOMER NAME: " + billingInfo.first_name + ' ' + billingInfo.last_name
  );

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    itemInfo.push(
        "Item #: " +  '' +
        (i + 1) +  '\n' +
        'Shirt Name: ' + items[i]["name"] + '\n' +
        'Size: ' + items[i]["size"] + '\n' +
        'Color: ' + items[i]["color"] + '\n' + 
        "Quantity: " + items[i]["quantity"]
    );
  }
```

but for some reason the stripe description is implemented like this:

[image]

Any idea how to get the description to create new lines in stripe dashboard to be sent to customer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `description` field is meant to be a single-line field to be shown in a web interface. It's not possible to format it as a multiline (Stripe will automatically remove any formatting).

Instead a better solution is to put the order ID in the `description` and place the actual items in metadata:

```
const checkout = await stripe.charges.create({
  amount: totalCost * 100,
  currency: "usd",
  description: `Order # ${id}`,
  receipt_email: billingInfo.email,
  source: token.id,
  metadata: {
    items: JSON.stringify(itemInfo),
  }
});
```

Then later you can show the contents of `metadata.items` to your user in a web view.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to have multi-line description for the items. I checked with Stripe Support about this feature, and it is still not supported at the moment.

> We don't see this being possible to do with Stripe Checkout. We can't
> guarantee that this feature will be implemented at the moment, but
> we’re rapidly evolving our product suites, so be sure to stay close to
> hear about new products and features as we announce them.